# Примитивный файловый менеджер на php (обучение)

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Решил обучить php и при написании простого файлового менеджера с возможностью уходить вглубь по папкам столкнулся с проблемой. После входа в дочернюю папку, не отрабатывает is_dir в цикле. т.е. папки которые есть внутри не оборачиваются ссылкой. при этом в корне, в директории, где находится обрабатываемый файл - всё ок.
Подскажите, где я ошибся или что пропустил?

```
$dir = isset($_GET['link']) ? scandir($_GET['link']) : scandir('.');

    if(isset($dir))
    {
        foreach($dir as $i)
        {
            if($i != '.' && $i != '..') 

            if(is_dir($i))
            {
                echo '<p><strong><a href="/program.php?link='.(isset($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'].'/'.$i : $i).'">[ '.$i.' ]</a></strong></p>';
            }
            else
            {
                 echo '<p>'.$i.'</p>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

is_dir проверяет имя папки внутри рассматриваемой. но ищет её относительно текущей. а текущая у тебя судя по всему та, откуда ты запускаешь этот самый поиск. и там такой папки нет. просто добавь в цикле в начале имени файла путь до текущей папки. путь станет абсолютным и is_dir сможет понять что это реальная папка.

Пример кода на базе того, что был в вопросе. Исправлены два участка - добавлена переменная в самом начале, и она же используется внутри if'а.

```
$currentDir = __DIR__ . '/' . (isset($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] . '/' : '');
$dir = scandir($currentDir);
if (isset($dir)) {
    foreach ($dir as $i) {
        if ($i != '.' && $i != '..') {
            if (is_dir($currentDir . $i)) {
                echo '<p><strong><a href="?link=' . (isset($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] . '/' . $i : $i) . '">[ ' . $i . ' ]</a></strong></p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>' . $i . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Можно запустить код в консоли так:

```
$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8008 /путь/до/этого/файла.php
```

И потом открыть в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8008/

Comment: При этом если вручную прописать путь к внутренней папке - работает, а ссылкой её не оборачивает...

Comment: В вашем случае есть жёсткая привязка к пути: `'/my/root/dir'`. Я использую `scandir('.')`, что более универсально и подойдёт к любой папке, куда пометить файл.

Comment: В моём случае это прототип. В твоём rootDir будет равен `__DIR__` и нет проблем.

Comment: если установить `__DIR__` не получится углубляться во внутренние папки, так как `__DIR__` останется неизменным по отношению обрабатываемого файла.

Comment: он и не должен меняться. `__DIR__` + выбранная_директория + доступные_для_выбора.

Comment: т.е. существующий код доработать/исправить не получится?

Comment: исправил код из вопроса. правок почти нет, но работает вроде как вы и ожидали. пробуйте.

Comment: Ваш код не работает. Ошибка в `:` в первой строчке.

Comment: проверил, всё работает штатно. скопипастил код из ответа и запустил. отлично взлетело. php 7.0.13